# Led panel sending and receiving card working

Tags: receiver, led-matrix, video-transmitter

I understand how a RGB LED panel is driven from sparkfun's explanation ([here](https://www.sparkfun.com/sparkx/blog/2650)).

From manufacturers like Huidu and Novastar I get that in a setup you often need a sending and receiving card. Like you could see ([here at page 3](http://download.huidu.cn/download/fullSpec/HD-A30A30+%20Spec.%20V3.0.pdf))

In which the sending card divides the image you would like to show to the right parts and sends it to the right receiving boards.

But I wonder how the communication happens for an asynchronous LED sending card, if you display a static picture.

- Does the sending card once send the needed information to the receiving cards and they buffer the data in their memory and display the image stored in the memory?
- Or does sender card continuously send the same static image to the receiving cards?

I would like to know this because I'm thinking about building my own asynchronous LED sender card and send the data to existing receiving cards.

Comment: "*... you often need a sending and receiving card.*" This seems to be terminology that you've made up. There is no reference to "sending", "receiving" or "card" in the linked article. Can you edit to clarify?

Comment: @Transistor I added extra information on that part.

Answer (score 1):

It's entirely up to you.

If you're only ever going to be showing static pictures, then the first option might make sense. The memory increases the cost of the receiving nodes, but the communications bandwidth is greatly reduced.

On the other hand, if you're sometimes going to be showing video, then the second option probably makes the most sense. You need the bandwidth anyway, so keep the node costs as low as possible.

If you want to build a sending card that works with an existing receiving card, then you need to learn from the manufacturer what the required protocol is. Such information may or may not be considered proprietary.